# Wordpress show old data on front end

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have used Jobify Theme with WP job manager. I am importing job listing directly in mysql from xml(from jobadder Api) using my custom code. Job listing is proper in admin panel, but wrong(old data) on front job listing page. There are some points that I checked that:-

wrong data only when select full listing without any search data.
If There is any keyword, category or location in search its showing new(correct) data.
Its showing new data on job detail page also. 
Admin panel job list also show new data.
when I click edit for any one job and update, even nothing change, its start showing new data everywhere.

get_posts() return old data as i check in code.

I have tried this link
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-job-manager-listing-jobs-with-wp-all-import

Please can anyone help me.

Comment: You should ask in Jobify Theme support. Please check if any caching plugin you are using and that prevent new data to load.

Comment: Thanks I am also post question on jobify theme site.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 20, 'offset'=> 1, 'post_type' => 'job_listing','post_status'      => 'publish' );
    $jobs = get_posts( $args );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for support.

My problem is solved. I update last inserted post(job_listing) using wordpress code. My code is

```html
<?php
           $type='job_listing';
         $id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 
                "
                    SELECT ID 
                    FROM wp_posts
                    WHERE post_type = %s
                    ORDER BY ID DESC limit 0,1
                ", 
                $type
            ) );
     $my_post = get_post($id);
     wp_update_post( $my_post );
?>
```